# Evitar Archivo usado por otro proceso

Tags: c#, xml, stream, filesystem

Buenas Se me pido realizar un archivo xml que anote el tiempo de juego en un XML.
Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
string IgtFilePath = Path.GetFullPath("IGT_Timer.xml"); 
int IgtMs = 0;
 private void IGTText()
        {
            File.WriteAllText(IgtFilePath, string.Empty);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(IgtFilePath))
            {
                switch (gameSelect)
                {
                    case 1:
                        IgtMs = sekiroSplitter.getTimeInGame();
                        writer.Write(IgtMs.ToString());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        IgtMs = ds1Splitter.getTimeInGame();
                        writer.Write(IgtMs.ToString());
                        break;                 
                    case 4:
                        IgtMs = ds3Splitter.getTimeInGame();
                        writer.Write(IgtMs.ToString());
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        IgtMs = eldenSplitter.getTimeInGame();
                        writer.Write(IgtMs.ToString());
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        IgtMs = celesteSplitter.getTimeInGame();
                        writer.Write(IgtMs.ToString());
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        IgtMs = cupSplitter.getTimeInGame();
                        writer.Write(IgtMs.ToString());
                        break;
                    case 3: //Ds2
                    case 6: //Hollow
                    case 0:
                    case 9:
                    default:
                        writer.Write("-1"); break;   
                }
            }
```

Las funciones getTimeInGame() devuelven un Int de la duracion del juego en Milisegundos.
El archivo sera leido por un proceso en javascript el cual no tengo idea su codigo.
tengo miedo de que si este proceso usa el archivo de IGTFilePath.
El programa salte con una excepcion de "Archivo siendo usado" como puedo prevenir esta falla?

> Nota: Se el archivo es actualizado cada 1ms.

Comment: agarra la excepcion que salga cuando hagas la apertura del archivo... no? o cual es el problema?

Comment: que es contante su uso, osea siempre va a estar en uso, si lo meto en la sentencia catch escribe igual?. Se me ocurre copiar el codigo 2 veces tanto si tira error como sino, el caso borde seria si escribe el string empty

Comment: no.. si entra al catch, quiere decir que no lo pudo abrir.. no deberias repetir tu codigo, si no volver a intentarlo.. el tema es como evitar que falle js en esos casos... si es que alguna vez cierra el archivo...

Comment: capas puedo decirle al que haga el js que abra y cierre el archivo asi deja tiempo a mi prog para actualizarlo, capas actulizar mi archivo cada 2ms y que el otro ms agarre el archivo lo lea saque la variable y lo vuelva a cerrar

Comment: las operaciones sobre archivos son dificiles de controlar por tiempo... ojo con eso... si el disco esta haciendo otra cosa, tus 2ms pasaron a ser 5... no es tan facil como pensas...